# I'm trying to customize a UITabbar using the following code without any luck

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to customize a UITabbar using the following code without any luck:

this is in my viewDidLoad method

```
 UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    // Set background for all UITabBars
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    // Set background for only this UITabBar
    [[self.tabBarController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
```

any idea where I might be going wrong here? thanks

Comment: Could you add this line `NSLog(@"%d", tabBackground != nil);` to your code, and see what gets printed, `0` or `1`? If you see `0`, the program cannot find the image.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the console outputs a "1"

Comment: I hope you have seen this link http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/

Comment: @hanumanDev OK, can you try the same exercise, but using `self.tabBarController` instead of `image`, like this: `NSLog(@"%d", self.tabBarController != nil);`? It looks like you are calling the right APIs, so my suspicion is that you are doing it at a wrong time, i.e. before some "moving target" is ready.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that outputs a '0'

Comment: @hanumanDev By chance, is your class where the `viewDidLoad` is called a `UITabBarController`? In this case, the last line should be `[self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it's a UIViewController not a UITabBarController. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the background color of UITabBar controller. Please refer the code which is    given below.Hope this helps you.

```
   tabBar1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
   UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:image];
   view.backgroundColor = color;
   [color release];
   [[self tabBar] insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
   [view release];
```